# How to extract the text and make them to a dictionary?

Tags: python, string

I have a string like this:

```py
s='Domaine de la Charbonniere 2016(B-L2-087-AB-356 ) x3 | Domaine de la 2016( D-L2-021-AB-647) x2'
```

Can somebody tell me how I can extract the texts and make it a dictionary like below:

```py
{'B-L2-087-AB-356':3, 'D-L2-021-AB-647':2}
```

The key is the code and the value is the quantity.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module for the task:

```py
import re

s = "Domaine de la Charbonniere 2016(B-L2-087-AB-356 ) x3 | Domaine de la 2016( D-L2-021-AB-647) x2"


out = {k: int(v) for k, v in re.findall(r"\(\s*(.*?)\s*\).*?x(\d+)", s)}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'B-L2-087-AB-356': 3, 'D-L2-021-AB-647': 2}
```